# testing a state change on react after calling an async method

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, nock, chai-enzyme

I have a React component that does something like:

**Component**

```
class CallBackend extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            message:"",
            loading:true
        };
    }

    callService = ()=>{
        axios.get("http://localhost:80/sample-url")
             .then(response=>this.setState({loading:false, message:response.data}))
             .catch(error=>this.setState({loading:false, message:error.message}));
    };

    render(){
        return(<p>{this.state.loading}</p>);
    }
}
```

and then, I want to test with **mocha** and **chai** that the state changes after I invoke the `callService` method:

**Unit Test**

```
it("should change the state value after calling the service",()=>{
    const clock = sinon.useFaketimers();
    nock("http://localhost:80").get("/sample-url").reply(200,"ok");
    const wrapper = shallow(<CallBackend/>);
    expect(wrapper.state().loading).to.equal(true);
    wrapper.instance().callService();
    clock.tick(500);
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.state().loading).to.equal(false);
});
```

I've tried using `wrapper.update()` or `sinon.fakeTimer()` or even calling `callService`as a Promise

```
wrapper.instance().callService().then(()=>{
    expect(wrapper.state().loading).to.equal(false);
});
```

With no result: `wrapper.instance().callService().then() is not defined`

Any other suggestions? I really don't want to end up using `setTimeout()` function